# How to solve No module named 'keras.saving.pickle_utils' error?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, pickle

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle
 
frameWidth= 640         # CAMERA RESOLUTION
frameHeight = 480
brightness = 180
threshold = 0.75         # PROBABLITY THRESHOLD
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

 
# SETUP THE VIDEO CAMERA
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
cap.set(10, brightness)
# IMPORT THE TRANNIED MODEL
pickle_in=open("model_trained.p","rb")
model=pickle.load(pickle_in)
```

this gives me this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.saving.pickle_utils'
How to solve it?

P.S: I'm trying to run this code on raspberry pi 3. I've installed tensorflow and its packages and tried to import tensorflow and keras, and I did not face any problem.

Answer (score 2):

try to downgrade your tensorflow version.

Look at this: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/18912